# Recurring meeting is missing from calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, calendar

I organized a recurrence meeting in Outlook. All of a sudden its missing. How do I fix this?

1. No problem from attendees point of view
2. From the Web also not showing
3. Tried to add from .ics format but nothing happens. It don't add into my calendar. Tried both from the Web and Outlook client
4. It is not deleted because its not in Deleted Items. I used the 'recover deleted items' feature but not found it

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to further confirm your question, please provide relevant information on the following questions for our better research:

- Have you done any special operations before this issue occurred?
- And is one series of circular meetings gone or are all series of meetings gone?
- Have you logged into your account on multiple devices and made changes on other devices?

Considering that different calendar events will be displayed in different views, please switch to the List view on the outlook client and search in this view to check if it exists.

[image]

In addition, I found a thread mentioned the similar issue, which introduced "when a user uses Microsoft Exchange ActiveSync on a mobile device to modify a recurring meeting, some recurring calendar items disappear from the "Day/Week/Month" view in Outlook. However, they can still be seen in the "By Category" view." Please refer to it and check if it's your issue:

[recurring calendar items disappear in Outlook](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/exchange/en-US/69b5de6b-61a5-400d-98ea-f56d07f22f84/recurring-calendar-items-disappear-in-outlook)

Comment: Hi. This definitely helps. I did modify from my phone. Just found out that I should not do that. For now, I deleted whole series and created a new one. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad to know that it helped. By the way, if you don't mind, you can mark my reply as an answer so that it could be benefitial toothers in the community looking for help on similar topics.